# Reading a form in wordpress with the plugin Exec-PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

We are using the Exec-PHP to use PHP in our wordpress page. But we got a problem, we cant read from a textfield form. Is this a Exec-PHP limmitation (If so could anyone recommend a plugin who does allow this) Or is something wrong in our code?

This is our code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text"  value="voornaam"  />
<input type="submit" value="Verzend" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    echo $_POST["voornaam"];
    echo 'Done';
}

?>
```

Comment: where is your 'voornaam' textfield?

Comment: Its in the code, but i forgot to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add:

```
<input type="text" value="voornaam" />
```

Then, in your PHP, you can use:

```
echo $_POST["voornaam"];
```

Your form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="voornaam" />
  <input type="submit" value="Verzend" />
  <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>
```